# Windows XP Remote Desktop (MSTSC.exe) to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a Windows XP phyiscal workstation and need to connect to a Windows 7 VM.

I am running in to errors they run RDP.

One rdp (mstsc.exe) launches and I accept the legal message and an error appears saying

“User name or password is incorrect”

I have created shortcuts with certain settings in it like:
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
But still no joy in fixing it.

The Windows XP has the KB Article KB969084 installed which gives them RDP 7.

I can stop the error only once by deleting certain registry keys, but on second login the error comes back.

There needs to be a more permanent fix for this, has anyone come across anything like this or has any ideas.

Cheers

EDIT : Also if I connect from a Windows 7 or a Windows server I do not get any issues, just from Windows XP SP3

Comment: on the win7 box, have you enabled the RDP setting "Allow connections from any version of the RDP client" (paraphrased, I don't have a win7 box handy).

Comment: yes sorry should have mentioned that too.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work for me I had to do the following. 
Goto the following link - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951608

1. Add the following registry keys on the Windows XP workstations Click
   Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. In the navigation pane, locate and then click the following registry
   subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
3. In the details pane, right-click Security Packages, and then click
   Modify. In the Value data box, type tspkg. Leave any data that is
   specific to other SSPs, and then click OK.
4. In the navigation pane, locate and then click the following registry
   subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
   In the details pane, right-click SecurityProviders, and then click
   Modify.
5. In the Value data box, type credssp.dll. Leave any data that is
   specific to other SSPs, and then click OK.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. Restart the computer.

I then tested and all worked.